# Store GmailAttachment content

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm reading the Gmail attachments using Google Apps Script:

```
message.getAttachments();
```

Then I iterate over the individual `GmailAttachment`s and send the content of the `GmailAttachment` (so the actual attachment, not the metadata) to my server endpoint.
At first, I tried using `getBytes()` method to extract the data. But when printed in the script, it contains just an Array of integers.
I also tried using getDataAsString(), but the data I received had a different encoding than the one downloaded directly ("manually") from Gmail.

How do I represent and store the data from `getBytes()` method to get the actual byte data and not just integers (to be able to later open it the same way one would open any file downloaded from Gmail)? Do I need to somehow convert the integers or is there a way to get the raw bytes?

Comment: You can perhaps treat `getBytes` as returning the character code: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792323/9337071 Note that I knew this was string content

Comment: @tehhowch In the end, I ended up using `Utilities::base64Encode` method to encode the byte data and sent it to the server, where I decoded it and stored into a file. But your comment sort of inspired me to do this.