# Google Apps Script: How to set headers with GmailApp.sendMail() or GmailApp.createDraft()

Tags: email, google-apps-script, email-headers

I'm trying to write a function that sends reminders to all who don't replied within a few days.

The problem is: [createDraftReply()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#createDraftReply(String)) and [reply()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replybody) will set recipient to my own mail address because the docs say:

> Reply to the sender of the last message on this thread using the replyTo address.

The last message, which should be replied to, is from me of course. The reply button in the gmail web interface sets the recipient "correct". In this case to the recipient from the last mail. I saw no way to do this with the provided Apps Script methods.

The next idea was to create a draft and then [update()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String)) it with the "correct" recipient. Unfortunately this breaks the reference to the original message. After analyzing was is going wrong I found out that after updating the drafts recipient the mail headers *References:* and *In-Reply-To:* disappear.

How can I set this headers to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why you don't use the replyAll() ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replyallbody,-options

Comment: @St3ph maybe that's a workaround but I don't want to send the reminder to myself.

Comment: How do you know that they haven't replied?

Comment: I check the sender from the last message. If it's me. They haven't replied yet.

Comment: @tehhowch yeah this looks great. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this done, you have to activate [Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) and use Gmail API in your script. You have to create a [message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) in which you can specify the `threadId` it will belong to and the recipient(s) to send it to, and then [send()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) the message.

As explained in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786588/reply-to-an-email-in-gmail-with-appscript-with-changed-recipients-ends-up-in-a-n), the [update()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String)) is not working because when you update a Draft (in this case, change the recipient address), the existing thread information disappears and you have to rebuild the message.

I'm not gonna go through all these steps, but if you have problems in the process of writing this, I'd advice you to check [the answer I provided the link of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786588/reply-to-an-email-in-gmail-with-appscript-with-changed-recipients-ends-up-in-a-n).

Comment: @lamblichus this is not true. Look what the docs say about this option: "an email address to use as the default reply-to address (default: the user's email address)".

Comment: So? The default is the user's email address, but you can set a different one with this parameter.

Comment: "an email address to use as the **default reply-to address**" This is not what 
 I'm looking for! I want to set the recipient of the actual draft/message that will be send. Not the reply-to address.

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok this sounds promising. thanks!