# Gmail apps script edit body before forwarding

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Gmail apps script to forward emails with a certain label ... But I'd like to edit the body of the message prior to forwarding.

```
function fwdFB(){


var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('fb');
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for(var m in threads){
    var messages = threads[m].getMessages();
    for(var y in messages){ messages[y].forward('w@yahoo.com',{from:'webmaster@gmail.com'}) }
    threads[m].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```

I'm unclear as to how to insert the `getBody()` method to edit the message. (Specifically, I want to delete a certain HTML chunk from the message. It's the same chunk in each message.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options of `forward(recipient, options)` do not offer an endpoint to modify the message body. You'll have to do it instead manually, by sending a message after modifying the body as desired.

**Sample:**

```
function fwdFB(){
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('fb');
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for(var m in threads){
    var messages = threads[m].getMessages();
    for(var y in messages){ 
     var oldBody = messages[y].getBody();
     var newBody = oldBody.substring(1, 10)+" PS: This is a modification."
     var oldSubject = messages[y].getSubject();
      var newSubject = "Fwd: "+ oldSubject; 
      GmailApp.sendEmail('w@yahoo.com', newSubject, newBody, {from:'webmaster@gmail.com'})
    }
    threads[m].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

If it is important for you to preserve the message history, you need to perform additional steps to thread the message. 
@tehhowch provides a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792323/11599789) of how to do so.

Comment: This will probably lose the thread/conversation information too

Comment: This is certainly true - unless you manually retrieve and insert the thread history. I am not aware through of a possibility to modify the body of a forwarded message directly.

Comment: One needs to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792323/9337071) to maintain thread info. I recommend just mentioning it and if the OP cares enough about it they will have a reference to start with.

Comment: Thanks. And no, I don't care about the thread. This is just used to automate some tasks since IFTTT's Gmail integration is now useless.

Comment: In this case you can just use the solution provide above!