# How to forward a Gmail email and add to the message body using GmailApp in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

The [`GmailMessage.forward`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object)) only has an `htmlBody` option. But if you use that, then the forwarded email does not include the original email's body/content. It only includes what you put in `htmlBody`.

How can I forward the email, add text, and include the original body?

```
var message = GmailApp.search(`...`)[0].getMessages()[0];

message.forward("...", {
  "htmlBody" : "hi"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to get the body of the message you are looking to forward:

```
function myFunction() {
    const message = GmailApp.search(`to:...@gmail.com`)[0].getMessages()[0];
    const forwarded = message.getBody(); // that is the body of the message we are forwarding.

    message.forward("....@hotmail.com", {
      "htmlBody" : "My email test?<br><br>" //adds your message to the body
            +
            "<div style='text-align: center;'>---------- Forwarded message ----------</div><br>" + forwarded, //centers
    });
    }
```

I made a sample code based on yours by searching messages that were sent to a specific email address and forwarding to a hotmail email address.

Edit:

Reference code and the importance of getting the body of the email can be found over this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855391/gmail-apps-script-edit-body-before-forwarding)

Comment: I will test this. Thanks. But why do I need to enable the Gmail API advanced service for this?

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove that and made a reference to a sample code from a thread.